# prolog family tree issue

Tags: prolog

When using the sibling rule from my knowledge base the question `?- issibling(jo,X).`
returns **ali** which is correct but also returns **jo** (meaning jo is the sister of jo). Any help would be appreciated.

```
mother(ali,jess).
father(dom,dan).
mother(ali,dan).
father(dom,jess).
father(dom,tom).
mother(ali,tom).
father(dom,george).
mother(ali,george).
mother(jo,tracey).

father(eddie,ali).
mother(jenny,ali).
father(eddie,jo).
mother(jenny,jo).

mother(belinda,dom).
father(kieth,dom).
mother(belinda,ben).
father(kieth,ben).

male(dom).
male(tom).
male(dan).
male(george).
male(eddie).
male(kieth).
female(jess).
female(ali).
female(jo).
female(jenny).
female(belida).
male(ben).
female(tracey).

isparent(X,Y):-father(X,Y).
isparent(X,Y):-mother(X,Y).
ischild(Y,X):-isparent(X,Y).

isgrandparent(X,Z) :- isparent(X,Y), isparent(Y,Z).
issibling(X,Y) :- father(F,X),father(F,Y),mother(M,X),mother(M,Y).
issister(X,Y) :- issibling(X,Y), female(X).
isbrother(X,Y) :- issibling(X,Y), male(X).
isaunt(X,Z) :- issister(X,Y),isparent(Y,Z).
isuncle(X,Z) :- isbrother(X,Y),isparent(Y,Z).
isson(X,Y) :- male(X),isparent(Y,X).
isdaughter(X,Y) :- female(X),isparent(Y,X).
iscousin(X,Y) :- isaunt(Z,Y),isparent(Z,X).
isnephew(X,Z) :-ischild(X,Y),issibling(Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider more readable code: instead of `issibling(X,Y)`, maybe `siblings(S1,S2)`.

It's of help to 'break' symmetrical relations, and to use more abstract relations as possible: I would try (untested example)

```
siblings(S1, S1) :- parent_of(P, S1), parent_of(P, S2), dif(S1, S2).
```

Instead of dif/2, (@<)/2 could be used as well.